# How to Prevent Big MyISAM Table from crashes

Tags: c#, php, .net, mysql, database

i have a table 30 GB MySQL MYISAM with 29 millions rows
Multiple crawlers are running all the time so that multiple programs keep inserting into table .
how do i prevent my table from crash until the table limit to about 80 GB ?
Is there any solution ?

Some of my common sql query is INSERT IGNORE, INSERT DELAYED...

Comment: postgreSQL? ok, I leave... -->[]

Comment: Are you saying it does crash , frequently ?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why your table is crashing, but for such a write-heavy table, you might want to consider InnoDB, as it provides row based locking, instead of locking the whole table for every write (which MyISAM does).

Comment: My test shows that InnoDB is a bit slow compared to MyISAM when it comes to inserting records in a big table. May be some config issue.